# HERE API Route Calculation suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, maps, here-api

I am experiencing some weird and really frustrating problems with the routing service of the HERE API. It was working totally fine till yesterday, but when I tested it today it shows nothing at first and then I get the following message in the console:

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=XXXXX&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!53.551084599999996%2C9.9936818&waypoint1=geo!42.14731201935119%2C24.73156194202602&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary request failed

and another 2 errors:

https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=Y94bXc6tWL5xKdfNAMuKVFYyixiGECdBdQozM_IFxLg&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!53.551084599999996%2C9.9936818&waypoint1=geo!42.14731201935119%2C24.73156194202602&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary 504 (GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://route.ls.hereapi.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?xnlp=CL_JSMv3.1.9.0&apikey=Y94bXc6tWL5xKdfNAMuKVFYyixiGECdBdQozM_IFxLg&mode=fastest%3Bcar&waypoint0=geo!53.551084599999996%2C9.9936818&waypoint1=geo!42.14731201935119%2C24.73156194202602&representation=display&routeAttributes=summary' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have no idea what caused these errors. I tried out previous versions of my code, whereby I am 100% sure it was working correctly, but now it is failing there as well.

The code, related to the routing:

```
showRoute() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.displayLocationInfo, () => {
                    this.$swal({ icon: 'warning', text: 'Моля разрешете достъп до данните за локация!' })
                }, { enableHighAccuracy: true });              
            }
        },
        displayLocationInfo(position) {
            const lng = position.coords.longitude;
            const lat = position.coords.latitude;

            this.$store.dispatch('setStartWaypoint', `geo!${lat},${lng}`)

            if (!this.$store.getters.getRoutingParameters['waypoint1']) {
                return this.$swal({ icon: 'warning', text: 'Моля изберете офис!' })
            }

            const routingParameters = this.$store.getters.getRoutingParameters
            const router = this.platform.getRoutingService();

            router.calculateRoute(routingParameters, this.onResult,
                function(error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                });
        },
onResult(result) {
        if (Object.keys(this.map.getObjects()).length > 0) {
            for (let object of this.map.getObjects()){
                if (object.id === 'route'){
                        this.map.removeObject(object);
                }
            }
        }
        var route,
        routeShape,
        startPoint,
        endPoint,
        linestring;
        if(result.response.route) {
            route = result.response.route[0];
            routeShape = route.shape;
            linestring = new H.geo.LineString();

            if (route.summary.distance < 1000) {
                this.distance = route.summary.distance + ' м'
            } else {
                this.distance = (route.summary.distance / 1000).toFixed(2) + ' км'
            }

            routeShape.forEach(function(point) {
                const parts = point.split(',');
                linestring.pushLatLngAlt(parts[0], parts[1]);
            });

            startPoint = route.waypoint[0].mappedPosition;
            endPoint = route.waypoint[1].mappedPosition;

            const routeOutline = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
                style: {
                    lineWidth: 6,
                    strokeColor: 'rgba(8, 48, 69, 0.5)',
                    lineTailCap: 'arrow-tail',
                    lineHeadCap: 'arrow-head'
                }
            });

            const routeArrows = new H.map.Polyline(linestring, {
                style: {
                    lineWidth: 6,
                    fillColor: 'white',
                    strokeColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                    lineDash: [0, 2],
                    lineTailCap: 'arrow-tail',
                    lineHeadCap: 'arrow-head' 
                }
            });

            const routeLine = new H.map.Group();
            routeLine.id = 'route'
            routeLine.addObjects([routeOutline, routeArrows]);

            const startMarkerIcon = new H.map.Icon(require('../assets/marker.svg'), {
                size: {
                    w: 42,
                    h: 60
                }
            })

            const startMarker = new H.map.Marker({
                lat: startPoint.latitude,
                lng: startPoint.longitude
            }, { icon: startMarkerIcon });

            const endMarker = new H.map.Circle({
                lat: endPoint.latitude,
                lng: endPoint.longitude
            }, 6);

            endMarker.setStyle({
                strokeColor: 'white',
                fillColor: 'rgba(8, 48, 69, 0.5)',
                lineWidth: 2
            })

            startMarker.id = 'route'
            endMarker.id = 'route'

            this.map.addObjects([routeLine, startMarker, endMarker]);

            this.map.getViewModel().setLookAtData({bounds: routeLine.getBoundingBox()});
        }
    },
```

Comment: Till yesterday your API key was valid, did you check its expiration date/time ?

Comment: It is still valid

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It just started to work again right now... Maybe someone of here staff could tell us what was wrong?

Comment: Yep. Mine started working again too. Probably it was just a temporary issue...?

Comment: I'm not aware of any issues, but as an FYI for the future, you can check our status for APIs here: https://status.here.com/status

Comment: Yeah the status page said that everything was up and running.. But it wasn't! ;)